# Присваивание в for

Tags: python, sqlite, for

У меня есть код, которым я из БД достаю количество монеток по порядку:

```
for coins in cur.execute("SELECT coins,name FROM persons ORDER BY coins"):
   print(str(coins[1]) + ' имеет ' + str(coins[0]) + ' Мяукоина/нов')
```

Выходит вот так:

```
Амина Белка имеет 3 Мяукоина/нов
Анастасия Ступина имеет 3 Мяукоина/нов
Данил Лис имеет 3 Мяукоина/нов
Настя Склокина имеет 3 Мяукоина/нов
Мариам Булгадарян имеет 3 Мяукоина/нов
Денис Яббаров имеет 3 Мяукоина/нов
Лукерья Ландсберг имеет 3 Мяукоина/нов
West Side имеет 98 Мяукоина/нов
Павел Чёрный имеет 102 Мяукоина/нов
```

Как заставить идти список наоборот от большего к меньшему, присвоить всё это в одну переменную, чтобы в последующем выводить одной командой.

Я конечно пробовал вставлять в эту штуку вместо принт присваивание переменной, но в итоге эта переменная равнялась только последнему значению.

Comment: `ORDER BY coins DESC` питон здесь вообще ни при чём, это основы sql. А про одну переменную непонятно ничего

Comment: Что бы в результате весь этот список из имён и монет был присвоен одной переменной

Comment: `одна_переменная = cur.execute("SELECT coins,name FROM persons ORDER BY coins DESC")`

Comment: <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0493BC60> 
((

Comment: Ну тогда `одна_переменная = cur.execute("SELECT coins,name FROM persons ORDER BY coins DESC").fetchall()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите собрать весь текст в одну переменную:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("c:/temp/test.db")
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
cur = conn.cursor()

qry = """SELECT coins,name FROM persons ORDER BY coins DESC"""

res = "\n".join(f"{row['name']} имеет {row['coins']} Мяукоина/нов" for row in cur.execute(qry))
print(res)

conn.close()
```

результат:

```
Павел Чёрный имеет 102 Мяукоина/нов
West Side имеет 98 Мяукоина/нов
Лукерья Ландсберг имеет 3 Мяукоина/нов
Амина Белка имеет 3 Мяукоина/нов
Денис Яббаров имеет 3 Мяукоина/нов
Настя Склокина имеет 3 Мяукоина/нов
Анастасия Ступина имеет 3 Мяукоина/нов
Мариам Булгадарян имеет 3 Мяукоина/нов
Данил Лис имеет 3 Мяукоина/нов
```

---

Но лучше все-таки работать (возвращать / передавать в качестве параметра) с набором записей (`list of tuples`), из которого очень легко получить текст в нужном вам формате всего одной командой:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("c:/temp/test.db")
cur = conn.cursor()

def top_n(cur, qry, n=-1):
    qry += f" LIMIT {n}"
    cur.execute(qry)
    return cur.fetchall()

qry = "SELECT coins,name FROM persons ORDER BY coins DESC"
```

примеры:

```
In [116]: top_n(cur, qry, 3)
Out[116]: [(102, 'Павел Чёрный'), (98, 'West Side'), (3, 'Лукерья Ландсберг')]

In [117]: top_n(cur, qry, 3)
Out[117]: [(102, 'Павел Чёрный'), (98, 'West Side'), (3, 'Лукерья Ландсберг')]

In [118]: res = "\n".join(f"{r[1]} имеет {r[0]} Мяукоина/нов" for r in top_n(cur, qry))

In [119]: print(res)
Павел Чёрный имеет 102 Мяукоина/нов
West Side имеет 98 Мяукоина/нов
Лукерья Ландсберг имеет 3 Мяукоина/нов
Амина Белка имеет 3 Мяукоина/нов
Денис Яббаров имеет 3 Мяукоина/нов
Настя Склокина имеет 3 Мяукоина/нов
Анастасия Ступина имеет 3 Мяукоина/нов
Мариам Булгадарян имеет 3 Мяукоина/нов
Данил Лис имеет 3 Мяукоина/нов
```

Answer (score 0):

```
coinsD = {}
for coins in reversed( cur.execute("SELECT coins,name FROM persons ORDER BY coins") ):
    coinsD[str(coins[1])] = str(coins[0])
```